# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dockerhost

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, docker, curl

I'm new to Docker and I am currently following a tutorial found on: https://www.ybrikman.com/writing/2015/11/11/running-docker-aws-ground-up/

I have just ran `sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 training/webapp:latest python app.py`
 with no issues, creating a running container, I then  run `curl http://dockerhost:5000`
 but get the error `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dockerhost`
 every single time and I'n not sure why.

Comment: This might help: `curl http://localhost:5000`